# -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch and Modal dialog (z-index problem)

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, mobile-safari

I want to use a Modal window which is defined within an `overflow-y: scroll;` window. The modal is supposed to be an overlay for 100% of the screen. When I use -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch to have a smooth scrolling on Safari, the Modal window **is only inside the div container**, instead of the **whole screen**, only on **iPhone browsers**

It works fine on the computer, but causes the issue on Chrome and Safari on iOS.

This is my code:

```
.overlay-blury {
  width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
  height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgb(105, 105, 105);
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 1;
  filter: blur(50px);
}

.overlay-100h {
  width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
  height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}


#message-content {
  min-height: 23em;
  height: 45vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

---

```
<div id="message-content">
    <div class="overlay-blury"></div>
    <div class="overlay-100h>Modal content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does nobody have a clue? :(

Comment: I really would like to help you, but I got no `iOS` device to reproduce it. I can only guess. Did you try `100vw` instead of `100%`?